# Horizontally and vertically center span and image

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, center

I'm stuck with this problem that takes me forever, I am making a portfolio website and I want to display the projects that I have done. I'm messing around with positions and centering but I can't seem to get it right.

What I want is to have the image and text vertically and horizontally centered, with the text overlapping the image.

I have made a JSFidlle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vw7ftzy8/1/

What I eventually want is this: https://jsfiddle.net/vw7ftzy8/4/ (but responsive)

```css
.projectTest {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 56px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.projectsImage1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.projectsImage1Ghost {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.text-center {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <span class="projectTest">A test project</span>
  <img class="projectsImage1" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c545.png">
  <div class="projectsImage1 projectsImage1Ghost"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you do not need to support old versions of IE, I would use a flexbox for class `.text-center`

Browser support for flexbox [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

More information on flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.projectTest {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 56px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.projectsImage1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.projectsImage1Ghost {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.text-center {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <span class="projectTest">A test project</span>
  <img class="projectsImage1" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c545.png">
  <div class="projectsImage1 projectsImage1Ghost"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

If the height of all the images is known (I'm seeing that you have used `200px` as a height), you can use [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) using the `translate function` (IE9+). This property when is applied in percents, take into account the size of the element instead of the size of its parent:

```css
.text-center {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.projectTest {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 56px;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 999;
}

.projectsImage1 {
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <span class="projectTest">A test project</span>
  <img class="projectsImage1" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c545.png">
</div>
```

Comment: This solution also works like it should! The reason why I chose the other one over this though is because the word break and styling is a bit more clean and better working in comparison to this one. Thank you very much nonetheless!

Comment: Thanks @sebas2201, I've removed the line breaks with the `white-space` parameter. You can remove it if you want word breaking.